# How and when should I test and adapt my Apex code to support ICU?

Tags: apex, locale

Salesforce adopted a new set of locale formats in Winter ’20 called ICU. When and how should I adapt my Apex code to support it?

Answer (score 7):

To meet the latest international standards for internationalization and localization, Salesforce adopted a new set of locale formats in Winter ’20 -- the [international Component for Unicode (ICU)](https://icu.unicode.org/).

A user’s locale determines the formats for dates, times, currencies, addresses, names, and numeric values. ICU sets the international standard for these formats for all locales. With ICU, Salesforce provides a consistent experience across the Salesforce platform and improves integration with ICU-compliant applications across the globe.

If your org was created in Summer ’19 or earlier, it had Oracle’s Java Development Kit (JDK) locale formats by default. In this case, you must migrate to the new formats, or Salesforce will enforce them in Spring ’23.

For more details and step-by-step instructions to adopt it (i.e. impact assessment, make relevant updates, and test) visit [this help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.icu_migration_overview.htm).

Have further questions? Ask them in the [ICU Locale Format Adoption Trailblazer Community group](https://sfdc.co/AdoptICU)